# ETbb conflict with tufte

Tags: fonts, tufte

Both ETbb.sty and tufte-common.def require textcomp:
The former: `\RequirePackage[full]{textcomp}`,
the latter: `\RequirePackage{textcomp}`.
The option  *full* causes an error message.

Should I remove the option from ETbb.sty or add it to tufte-common.def?
Or something else?

```
% MWE
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{ETbb}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, loading `textcomp` should be no longer required. Anyway, you can fix the issue by passing the `full` option also when the `tufte-book` class is loaded.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{full}{textcomp}
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{ETbb}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Also it is great to know the existence of \PassOptionsToPackage: 
it is not necessary to edit .sty and .def. files!